# How do I sign into Chrome but not gmail?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

This is sort of the opposite of:
[Sign out of chrome but use gmail](https://superuser.com/questions/1360836/sign-out-of-chrome-but-use-gmail). I want to sign into chrome but **not** use gmail. This *used* to work, but... updates.

I use several dummy gmail accounts to sync Chrome profiles for different web projects I work on. How can I sign into Chrome but not gmail and related services? It seems the two are tied together now.

Comment: You don’t.  When you log into Chrome you log into your Google account.  Google uses a SSO for all their services.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- In Chrome, enter into the address bar: `chrome://flags/#account-consistency`
- Find the entry "Identity consistency between browser and cookie jar".
  The drop-down box next to it should read "Default".
- To disable the sign-in link, click the drop-down box and set it to "Disabled".
- Restart Chrome.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to sign me out of gmail... and when I do it still pauses syncing in chrome